# Unable to get from Microsoft forms into PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I am trying to pull the data from Microsoft forms such as number of response and overall data into power bi. I referred to this link https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/forms-and-flow-and-powerbi/ for the overall process. Yet I couldn't retrieve data from the flow as the picture shows below. Is there any solution for this?
[image: Flow&BI]

Comment: Your first sentence is difficult to understand due to the English, can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting it wrong,

You wish to pull data from Ms Forms Pro. Forms Pro has entities in [CDS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/data-platform-intro)

In layman's Term Forms Pro has below tables been saved in Database hold by CDS (which is also called as Dynamics 365 data model) [Link for Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/forms-pro/developer/forms-pro-reference)

[image]

Now to pull/fetch data from any of the entities mentioned above from Power BI, you will have to connect with CDS (Dynamics 365)

How do you connect CDS in PowerBI.

Here are few Links

- [Link 1](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/cds-for-apps-powerbi/)
- [Link2](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2018/10/connect-to-the-power-bi-using-common-data-service-cds/)